# How to merge two arrays of object

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hey there I am working with section list and i need to fetch data 10 items by 10 items the first fetch work properly and good but the second give me a lots of problems.

My first fetch give me data like this

```
[
{
title: '28/01/2020',
data: [{location: madrid, city: madrid,...}, {location: barcelona, city: barcelona,...}]
},
title: '29/01/2020'
data: [{location: rabat, city: rabat,...}, {location: alger, city: alger,...}]
]
```

and the second fetch should give me data with same title for example

```
[
{
title: '29/01/2020',
data: [{location: londer, city: londer,...}, {location: rio, city: rio,...}]
},
title: '30/01/2020'
data: [{location: new york , city: new york ,...}, {location: roma, city: roma,...}]
]
```

How can I merge with those two arrays and have an array like this so I couldn't have duplicate title.

```
[{
title: '28/01/2020',
data: [{location: madrid, city: madrid,...}, {location: barcelona, city: barcelona,...}]
},
title: '29/01/2020',
data: [{location: rabat, city: rabat,...}, {location: alger, city: alger,...}, {location: londer, city: londer,...}, {location: rio, city: rio,...}]
},
title: '30/01/2020'
data: [{location: new york , city: new york ,...}, {location: roma, city: roma,...}]
]
```

Comment: Can you put some code what you are trying

Comment: i tried a lot of codes but i finaly delete them all and ask this question here i wanna just merge the duplicate title in one object title with all data from all duplicate title

Answer (score 0):

You can definetly merge the two arrays by doing :

```
let newArr = [...arr1,...arr2];
```

And you can work upon removing duplicates on this by :

```
newArr = newArr.filter((thing, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.title === thing.title
  ))
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i dont wanna filter arrays from duplicate i wanna merge dublicat title in one object

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
let arr1 = [
{
  title: '28/01/2020',
  data: [
  {
    location: 'paris',
    city: 'paris'
  },
  { 
    location: 'paris',
    city: 'paris'
    }
    ]
},
{
  title: '29/01/2020',
  data: [
  {
    location: 'paris', city: 'paris'
   },
   {
    location: 'paris', city: 'paris'
    }
   ]
 }
];

let arr2 = [
{
  title: '28/01/2020',
  data: [
  {
    location: 'paris',
    city: 'paris'
  },
  { 
    location: 'paris',
    city: 'paris'
    }
    ]
},
{
  title: '30/01/2020',
  data: [
  {
    location: 'paris', city: 'paris'
   },
   {
    location: 'paris', city: 'paris'
    }
   ]
 }
];

let newArr = arr1.concat(arr2.filter( ({title}) => !arr1.find(f => f.title == title) ));





console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: but here u didnt concat the data of '28/02/2020' u only choose one

Answer (score 0):

You can first reduce into one object to have unique keys and get their values.
You can extend the function to allow more arrays.

```js
let merged = (data1, data2) =>
  Object.values(
    [...data1, ...data2].reduce(
      (acc, curr) => ({
        ...acc,
        [curr.title]:
          curr.title in acc
            ? { ...curr, data: [...acc[curr.title].data, ...curr.data] }
            : { ...curr }
      }),
      {}
    )
  );

const data1 = [
  {
    title: "28/01/2020",
    data: [
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      },
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "29/01/2020",
    data: [
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      },
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const data2 = [
  {
    title: "28/01/2020",
    data: [
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      },
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "30/01/2020",
    data: [
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      },
      {
        location: "paris",
        city: "paris"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(merged(data1, data2));
```

Comment: but u must have 4items in the data of '28/01/2020' why we have only  two?

Comment: u can say it worket but in other way it caused multiple fetch data from server i dont understand that there is no problem in my fetch code cz it work properly when i delete this code thanks btw

Comment: @HamzaElm, Interesting. Can you share your code in question or some sandbox, So that can understand the problem?